# Different behavior of Foundation 6 Top Bar Menu for two (nearly) similar pages

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6, textpattern

I created a draft for a website with Foundation 5 (F5) and Textpattern. But I decided to upgrade my documents to Foundation 6 (F6) some months after it was released. Unforunately, I'm not really happy with the new menu structure (so far...) and will try some other things out with Foundation's Building Blocks etc. But first, I need to find out the reason of a different behavior of the F6 Top Bar menu bar for two of my pages:

1. The Top Bar is looking OK on the home page: http://frickeln.jensfreyer.de/ But...
2. ...the menu toggle + menu/submenu function does not at another place: http://frickeln.jensfreyer.de/blog/.

Do you have an idea why this happens? The html documents are reduced to the max. and a comparison of the source codes doesn't tell me why. But possibly you see it... and I overlooked sth. (I would be happy).

I'm using Foundation 6.1.2 and Textpattern 4.5.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the blog page, `foundation.min.js` and `jquery.min.js` are not linked correctly, in the console they are shown as NOT found.

I think instead of

```
http://frickeln.jensfreyer.de/blog/js-6.1.2/vendor/jquery.min.js
```

it should link to

```
http://frickeln.jensfreyer.de/js-6.1.2/vendor/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: Thank you very much! A simple "/" as reference to root directory of the site solved the issue because of your really helpful answer. I just didn't realized that the blog page has another URL... due to some kind of "blindness" while was checking the documents for consistency. ;-) Thanks again, Shoaib!